# How to use String interpolation in Angular for units

Tags: angular

Hi i am new to Angular.

How can i use string interpolation in Angular if the array contains like this:

```
[{height(cm):122, weight(kg):54 }]
```

If i use this array in table using `*ngFor` i am getting an error like `height is not a function`

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let units of chars">
    <td>{{units?.weight(kg)}}</td>
    <td>{{units?.height(cm)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Any solution will be helpful?TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a field name has characters with special meanings (such as `()` in your code, which are considered a function call), you need to use the field name in quotes.

```js
let a = [{'height(cm)':122, 'weight(kg)':54 }]

a[0].height(cm) // error
a[0]['height(cm)'] // works
```

So, replace

```js
{{units?.weight(kg)}}
```

with any of these:

```js
{{units['weight(kg)']}} // without null check
{{units?.['weight(kg)']}} // with null check
```

Comment: It worked for me like a pro.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the brackets at the end of the words height and weight which confuses the compiler.

Rather try this:

```
[{heightInCm:122, weightInKg:54 }]

<tr *ngFor="let units of chars">
    <td>{{units.weightInKg}}</td>
    <td>{{units.heightInCm}}</td>
</tr>
```